# How to launch a coroutine that keeps running after the suspending function caller returns?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

For example, from a suspending function, how do we launch a coroutine to fire-and-forget an http request? That is, the suspending function launching the coroutine can return while the http request may be in-flight. (e.g. to trigger a side-effect http request to capture analytics/metrics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just fire-and-forget coroutine you don't even need suspend function. You can just use `GlobalScope`

```
fun test() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        while (true) {
            delay(1000)
            println("I'm alive")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: avoid the `GlobalScope` please

Comment: why? It seems ok for fire-and-forget things

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc)

Comment: yep, when I'm launching a fire-and-forget job I don't want to track its completion. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: It's all about use cases. You wouldn't use `GlobalScope` for a simple console app, because of the reasons mentioned in the provided article. But, suppose you have a webapp that runs continuously in a context of some Tomcat. If Tomcat or the webappp fails and halts, the interrupted coroutine is your least problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
fun abc(){
     GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    delay(10000)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e(e)
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you are inside the coroutine, you should just save the suspending function return type in a variable and that's all.

For example, if you do:

```
coroutineScope.launch{
 thisIsASuspendingMethod()
 thisIsAlsoASuspendingMethod()
}
```

No one can assure you that the first method will end its execution first, because that is what a `suspend` method does, runs slow code.

But, if you use:

```
coroutineScope.launch{
     val retreiveData = thisIsASuspendingMethod()
     if(retreiveData.isSucessful()){
       thisIsAlsoASuspendingMethod()
     }
    }
```

And also, I suggest you to read more about coroutines, just because of this statement you make:

> For example, from a suspending function, how do we launch a coroutine
>   to fire-and-forget an http request

Coroutines are launched in order to run the `suspend` methods, not otherwise. 
Since coroutines just run slow code, you may want to consider a suspending method inside the suspending method.